# program that looks for given image in screen

Tags: java, image

I wrote a small program in Java to look for a given image on the screen and return its coordinate. The program compiles just fine but for some reasons, it hasn't been able to locate the image.

it goes something like this:

the program receives a buffered image as input

The image should be something like this

[image: image would be something like this]

the following code to take a screenshot of the screen

```
screen= new Robot().createScreenCapture(new r 
                     rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
```

Sample screenshot:

[image: sample screenshot of screen]

(ideally, the program would return the coordinate of the google chrome icon)

the program tries to locate the image by iterate through every pixel in the screen and try to match it with the pixels of the given image through a quad for loop

```
for(int x = 0; x< screen.getWidth()-image.getWidth();x++){
     for(int y = 0; y< screen.getHeight()-image.getHeight();y++) {                                                   
           w=x,h=y;
           //a new rectangle is "drawn" reset the flag
           for(int a = 0; a< image.getWidth();a++){
              for(int b = 0; b< image.getHeight();b++){
                  //checks that pixel in screen matches the same pixel in the 
                  //image. if yes increment h value. if no change flag to true
                  //and breaks the loop
              }
              //checks the flag if true breaks loop other wise increment w 
              //value value
           }
           //here is the end of the "rectangle trial", if the image checks out 
           //the coordinate (w,h) will be the bottom right pixel of the image in 
           //screen. take that coordinate and return it
     }
}
after checking every pixels return coordinate (-1,-1) so that i know image doesnt exisit in the screen
```

the idea is that I match each pixel in the screen(except for the pixels that are on the right and bottom edges) with the pixels in the image. (imagine a rectangle of the size of the image is drawn for each pixel of the screen starting from cord (0,0) and if any pixel in the rectangle doesn't match the pixel of the same coordinate in the image, the for loop will break and the program moves on to the next pixel in the screen)

the following code is what's inside the for loops

```
for(int x = 0; x< screen.getWidth()-image.getWidth();x++){
            for(int y = 0; y< screen.getHeight()-image.getHeight();y++){//screen sized iteration
                f=x;
                g=y;
                flag=false;
                for(int a = 0; a< image.getWidth();a++){
                    for(int b = 0; b< image.getHeight();b++){//image sized 
                        if(screen.getRGB(f,g) != image.getRGB(a,b)){
                            flag=false;
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            g++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag){
                        break;
                    }else{
                        f++;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag) {
                    returnCoords=new Coords(f-image.getWidth()/2,g-                
                    image.getHeight()/2);
                    return returnCoords;
                }
            }

        }

        return returnCoords;
    }
```

the program should output the center coordinate of the image should it be part of the screen. if it isn't part of the screen the program returns (-1.0,-1.0) instead. however, no matter what image I input (44.0,-50.0) is the coordinate it returns

below is the compiled code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageScanner {     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException{
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\my projects\\Capture.PNG"));
        Coords x=ImageScanner.scanImage(image);

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove((int)(x.getX()),(int)(x.getY()));
    }
    public static class Coords{
        int x;
        int y;
        public Coords(int width,int height){
            x=width;
            y=height;
        }
        public int getX() {
            return this.x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return this.y;
        }

    }
    public static Coords scanImage(BufferedImage image) throws IOException, HeadlessException, AWTException {

        BufferedImage screen=null;

        screen= new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        int f=0;
        int g=0;
        int mismatched=0;

        ImageScanner.Coords returnCoords = new ImageScanner.Coords(-1,-1);

        for(int x = 0; x< screen.getWidth()-image.getWidth();x++){
            for(int y = 0; y< screen.getHeight()-image.getHeight();y++){//screen sized iteration
                f=x;
                g=y;
                mismatched=0;

                for(int a = 0; a< image.getWidth();a++){
                    for(int b = 0; b< image.getHeight();b++){//image sized 
                        if(screen.getRGB(f,g) != image.getRGB(a,b)){
                            mismatched++;
                        }
                        else{
                            g++;
                        }
                    }
                    g=y;
                    f++;
                }

                if((mismatched/((float)image.getWidth()*(float)image.getHeight()))<0.2) {
                    returnCoords=new Coords(f-image.getWidth()/2,g+image.getHeight()/2);
                    return returnCoords;
                }
            }

        }

        return returnCoords;
    }

}
```

Edit: Thank you the program now works

[output i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82kH8.png)

Comment: My bad this program is written in Java

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). To create an MCVE / SSCCE for this task, will require a large image that contains a small image. One way to do that is to get a screenshot then get a (random) subimage from that. Alternately, you might do the same with an image created in memory, or one hot-linked from one of the larger, non animated images [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: Hi, i am quite new to this site so sorry about the confusion. I have updated my question hopefully it is clearer now. thanx

Comment: Did you carefully read both the other links I provided? I ask because adding further uncompilable code snippets is not something I suggested you do. I also had the same understanding of what you are attempting as I held before the addition of images into the question. Edit to post an MCVE / SSCCE that is truly complete & self contained and I might look further into it. Otherwise .. good luck.

Comment: i'm not quite sure what u mean by your comment but i just compressed the program into a single file. hope that clears things up. thanks

Comment: `C:\\Users\\Tony\\eclipse-workspace\\Spam\\src\\A.PNG` Surprising as it may seem, I'm not Tony and don't have an image named `A.PNG` in that path. How do you expect anyone else to run this code to reproduce the problem? I've offered tips earlier on getting a small image, and a larger image in which to search for it. Any of those ways might work for other people, using images located on your PC, won't.